# How hard is it to dissolve an HOA?

Tags: texas, hoa, real-property

In Texas, and in the county I'm speaking of, to dissolve or drop out of an HOA there needs to be a 2/3 majority of property owners (1 vote per property) voting in the affirmative in order for a section to drop out of or abolish an HOA.

An obvious answer might be to consult an attorney, but I'm curious about a few things:

Can the HOA add new CC&Rs or new rules to make it 'illegal' to try to disband it? Can they retaliate against anyone trying to organize such a vote, such as harassing them about rules (which are NOT in the CC&Rs) a homeowner is 'violating' including fines that double each day? etc.

This is only hypothetical but I'm curious about it, the mechanics involved in getting it abolished, and whether or not the board can just vote on new CC&Rs to enforce on a whim? It's my understanding that only the CC&Rs in effect at purchase time are binding on a homeowner.